# Why can't I use a View containing a Union in Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, view, union

I have a View which looks similar to this:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Users
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as [Id], NULL as [Name]
```

When I try to map to this view in Entity Framework, it just fails. I don't get an error, but the view does not exist in my data store. Why is this? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because Visual Studio cannot infers the Primary Key of your View.
You can see the error message within edmx file by open it with XML editor and see the SSDL section.
Here is error message that results from my Model(which I created some View like yours within my Database just to emulate) :

```
Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6013: The table/view 'PhoneBook.dbo.ContactCustomer' does not have 
a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred.
This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, 
you will need to review your schema, 
add the correct keys, and uncomment it.
```

It is not true that Union is not supported in EF 4. 
But I think the problem is that Visual Studio saw your view as the odd View.

You can doing some experiment by create another View and compares them (using update model from database menu within model designer).

And you can modify the Model by hand (manual typing the edmx file) to define the Primary Key to resolve this.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an older question already marked as answered, but I wanted to post an alternative to editing the edmx.  I learned this one the hard way, after tons of Google searches and pulling my hair out for hours, trying different options...

For a view, EF attempts to to infer a primary key by identifying columns that are non-nullable
and non-binary (see [Create an Entity Key When No Key Is Inferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd163156%28v=vs.103%29)).

With a view used to flatten related data for lookup purposes, this can result in many columns (or the wrong ones) being inferred as keys.

For a view with a UNION, it can cause the opposite problem, because there may be no true identity column that can be safely included as a key.

To force EF to identify columns as a key, you can use ISNULL() to ensure the value is non-nullable:  `ISNULL(column_name, replacement_value)`

To force EF to not mark a column as a key, you can use NULLIF() to make it nullable: `NULLIF(column_name, value_not_equal_to_parameter_1)`

If you need to ensure a value is returned, but don't want to have it marked as a key, I believe `COALESCE(column_name, replacement_value)` will do the job of ISNULL without EF marking the column as a key

**If there is truly no viable column available** as a primary key (as in a UNION view), you can fake a non-nullable PK through the use of ISNULL() combined with ROW_NUMBER() in your SELECT statement: `SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort_criteria), 0) as 'ALIASNAME'`

As an alternative, the edmx can absolutely be edited directly as Marcos Prieto suggested, but you run the risk of having those changes overwritten the next time you run "Update Model from Database".

Hope this helps anyone who encounters this in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I had a view that worked perfectly. I modified it (changed the view on a union of 2 tables), updated the model from database and this problem appeared.

I fixed it in 3 steps:

1. Open the .edmx file with a XML editor.
2. Uncomment the view's EntityType XML (edmx:StorageModels > Schema) code and add the Key:

   ```
   <EntityType Name="your_view">
      <Key>
         <PropertyRef Name="your_id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="your_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="other_field" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" />
   </EntityType>
   ```
3. Be sure that EF didn't erased the view in edmx:StorageModels > Schema > EntityContainer (if you have code repository, copy the code from there):

   ```
   <EntitySet Name="your_view" EntityType="Your_Model.Store.your_view" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="your_schema" store:Name="your_view">
       <DefiningQuery>SELECT
          `your_view`.`your_id`, 
          `your_view`.`other_field`, 
           FROM `your_view` AS `your_view`
       </DefiningQuery>
   </EntitySet>
   ```

Comment: I know this is quite old however the compiler doesn't recognise the namespace prefix 'store'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i faced this issue recently & after trying to do the above mentioned methods i simply created another view that selects from the Union view & i was able to map the new view by updating my entity model.